# How to discover role instances in Azure?

Tags: .net, azure, cloud

The code below only prints one instance id per instance even though I'm running 4 instances.
Is this a bug in development fabric or this is how it is supposed to be?

```
public override void Run()
{
    foreach (RoleInstance roleInst in RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Instances)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Instance ID: " + roleInst.Id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have at least one internal endpoint for all the role instances to show up.

Comment: No good reason, as far as I know.  In some sense it makes sense (what would the point be of discovering the other instances if you had no way to interact with them?), but I have a feeling we'll change this in the future.  I'll ping our developer platform team.

Comment: Thanks smarx. One possible use case is that instances communicate with each other using a queue or table or some other hosted medium.

Comment: How upto date is the RoleEnvironment instances?

Comment: @smarx Any update with this issue? Are you going to make possible discovering another instances even without endpoints? Thx!

Comment: I left Microsoft last year, so I don't have any information about this anymore.